# Are there any potential issues with // in a img src file path?

Tags: html, src

Simple question, hope fully someone can help. 
One of my img tags has `https://s0.2mdn.net/creatives/assets//6870555/image.jpg`.

Even with the double `//`, it works as expected and doesn't seem to present any issues in chrome, firefox and IE10+.

To be clear the double `//` is referencing the slashes after 'assets' not the https://.

Can anyone confirm that this filepath structure isn't an issue?

Thanks All,
Moe

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be double //? single / without https: is for relative path

Comment: The double `//` is referencing the slashes after `https://s0.2mdn.net/creatives/assets`. Sorry I should've been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a link to a web page, then yes that is not an issue at all.

Comment: Sorry @Amorris I was referencing the `//` after 'assets' in the file path, not the `https:`. I've edited the post to clear that up.